# Pine Script Boxes are extending up and down

Tags: plot, pine-script, drawing

I'm new to Pine Script and trying to draw a box on a chart. The code is very simple:

```
this_box = box.new(left = bar_index - 1, top = high, right = bar_index + 50, bottom = low, border_color = na, border_width = 1, bgcolor = color.new(color.red, 70), extend = extend.none)
```

My "top" and "bottom" inputs are not taken into consideration, and the box goes all the way top and down. Did I miss smth?

[Box in TradingView chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7mRjZ.png)

I set extend to none, even though it's only about horizontal extending.

Comment: Please share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The code you shared does not match the image. You will need to share the code that is giving ***you*** issues. The code itself is correct and will plot at the last bar and extend 50 bars ahead.

Comment: @RakeshPoluri that's exactly the issue! The code is simple, it's just that, but the box is stretched up and down, I can't figure out how to stop it at hi / low / or any other value

Comment: @vitruvius sorry you can't reproduce the problem, but the code is really simple, just what I shared

Comment: There must be something else. The code you shared is fine.Why can't I reproduce it?